How to add 'additionallyAllowedTenants' in Databricks config or PySpark config?
I have a multi-tenant Azure app. I am using this app's credentials to read ADLS container files from Databricks cluster using PySpark dataframe.
I need to set this 'additionallyAllowedTenants' flag value to '*' or a specific tenant_id of the multi-tenant app in the databricks cluster config or PySpark session.
In Python I can achieve this by executing the below line of code:
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential(additionally_allowed_tenants=['*'])

My query is, how can I achieve the same in Databricks config or PySpark session. Any leads are appreciated.

To configure access to Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) in Databricks or PySpark, you need to set up the required Spark configuration properties for authentication.
This often involves using a service principal with its client ID, client secret, and tenant ID.
Although this does not directly configure additionally_allowed_tenants, it enables authentication through the credentials of a multi-tenant application by specifying the tenant ID.
You can try the below code:
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<application-id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")


I have configured Spark to access Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) using OAuth 2.0 authentication in a Databricks environment
In the above code I have created secret scope in aure databricks. A secret scope is collection of secrets identified by a name.

Know more how to create Create an Azure Key Vault-backed secret
scope
Also know more about access storage using a service principal & Microsoft Entra ID(Azure Active Directory)

dbutils.secrets.get to retrieve a secret stored in Azure Key Vault.
The secret is stored under a scope named "Key-vault-secret-dbx" and the specific key is "secretkv".
setting the authentication type for accessing the Azure Data Lake Storage account named "dilipstgdls" to OAuth 2.0.
OAuth provider type as ClientCredsTokenProvider, which is used to authenticate using client credentials (client ID and client secret).
Setting the client ID associated with the Azure AD application that will be used for authentication.
Setting the client secret, which is the credential retrieved earlier from Azure Key Vault, for authenticating the Azure AD application.

Thanks for your response. Exactly what you said I was using it for the single tenant app, but the same is not working for multi-tenant app. Somehow it needs 'additionally_allowed_tenants' param value. I coun't find a way to implement this using Azure Service Principle.
